# Running Scons with two Python installations on Windows

Tags: python, windows, scons

I have installed two different python versions (3.1 and 2,7) And this is now causing a headache. The default installation is the 3.1 which have the PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH set. Problem is that when I try to run scons from the 2.7 installation (via Python27/Scripts/scons.bat) I get various import errors that reference to the Python31/lib/ folder.

Are there any good solutions for this, except changing PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH for the whole system. Shouldn't scons be able to work with two versions of python installed?

*Not sure if this is a SuperUser or a SO question, but my guess that most people experienced with Python and Scons hangs here, and not in SU.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `PYTHONHOME` and `PYTHONPATH` in the `scons.bat` scripts to the right values for each Python installation respectively.

Comment: Good idea, I did this, and got another error message about failing to find site.py or something. Then I also tried moving the current PYTHONPATH at the beginning of the PATH variable. And then everything was working perfectly. I guess editing the scons.bat is a acceptable solution, although I will have to change it with each upgrade of scons. Thank you very much.